# Internationalization-of-dynamic-data-in-angular

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I am using internationalization [i18n] in my angular project. For static content it is working properly. But dynamic content it is not working.

My code is as follows:

**Static:**

```
     <div>{{ 'ADD ENTRY' | translate }} </div>
```

**Dynamic:**

```
    <div>{{ status | translate }} </div>
```

I am getting status code from the back end API, that I am mapping to the variable **status** in the ts file.
In my case I am getting status code as **404**. So I reconfigured that 404  in **i18n** configuration file. 
But it is not working if I try to translate that variable.But instead of passing that status variable, if I directly pass **'404'** as string then the internationalization working properly.

**My code is as follows:**

```
    <div class="error" *ngIf="status">**{{ '404' | translate }} **</div>
```

for this internationalization working.

But I need to internationalize the variable status, but facing issue.

**My code is as follows:**

**In HTML:**

```
  <div class="error" *ngIf="status">{{ status | translate }} </div>
```

**In ts:**

```
    status: string;
    this.status = error.status;
```

I also tried as:

```
        <div class="error" *ngIf="status">{{"'"+{{status}}+"'"}} | translate}}</div>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Better is if you Update your question instead of commenting here

Comment: Are you sure the error.status is string? Else in ts file change that to:
this.status = error.status + "";

Answer (score 0):

Try translating that dynamic text in `ts` file this way:

First set `TranslateService`:

`import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';`

`constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) { }`

and then, in a place where you'll recive the text (which in this case, I assume, is stored in `error.status`) do this:

`this.status = this.translateService.instant(error.status)`

and don't use `| translate` in html then, just put `status` there.